# how to get data using Jquery autocomplete when spacebar is pressed?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm implementing the jquery autocomplete, Here goes the code,

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#tags" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Here goes the HTML code:

```
 <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>

 <textarea rows="3" cols="50" id="tags"></textarea>
```

Now the problem is, when i type "a" or "s" I get the related data from autocomplete. I want to implement in such a way that when i press "space bar", I need to get all the data's. How do I go about it. Pls help...

Comment: Do you mean you want a data dump?

Comment: When i press spacebar, i need all the data's ie,.. "Action script", "Apple Script" & "Scheme". All the 3 data's.

Answer (score 0):

if you can define a function extractAll you can do as below

```
if(request.term == " ")
    response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        availableTags, extractAll() ) );
    else
    response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
```